# How can we sure Connection.close() is called

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am working on Spring MVC + Mysql using JDBC (Non Hibernate). In project we have many services which does the CRUD work. for each method we have to do some steps like

- open `Connection`
- Rollback on error
- Close `connection` in finally

Many developers are working on the same project and its very hard to check if connection is closed in finally by every one or not.

So is their any way where after completion of method connection get closed. can i write any class which check if execution of current method is done then close the connection.

**Update**

Or can we develop some class from which each developer have to ask for `Connection` will do work on the connection object the at the finally every one have to pass that object to destroyer. If destroyer is not called the show compile time error on that method.

Something like:

```
someMethod()
{
  Connection connection=null
  try
  {
Connection connection =icrudOperation.getConnection();

//do work with connection object like preparedStatement etc.
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   //logging
  }
  finally
  {
   icrudOperation.destroy(connection); // if this is not written by any one then at compile time error will shown for this method.
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that many application servers pool connections and closing it in code might not have any effect on the actual connection. Make sure that the web/app servers on developers' local machines are properly configured...

Comment: Use the Spring JdbcTemplate. That's one of its good features. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc

Comment: Thank you to both you. ll check the link provided. i updated the question can you check wther its possible or not.

Comment: It should work. You can also use AOP for your case, or Spring MVC interceptors - both of these are ways to have code run at the end of each call.

Comment: However, the problem is that if the JDBC connection pool is managed by your app server, the *underlying* connection is not actually destroyed when the object is closed or destructed. It is simply passed back into the app server's pool. At least that's how it works in .NET, but I am pretty sure Java is the same concept.

Comment: Ideally, however, you would encapsulate the connection into DAO or Repository objects which would manage it on their own... Your service methods should not be creating and destroying connections on each call, that's generally considered bad practice (and something one of my past employers really shot themselves in the foot with). Then, your DAO object would call close in its finalizer or whatnot.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes in my application we are using `c3p0` to manage pool it will be okay if its return to pool at least.

Comment: @Ruslan Excuse Me sir, but i am not getting this line `Your service methods should not be creating and destroying connections on each call`. currently we having service methods in whcih `getConnection()` is called from an class which manage datasource (pool) and in finally we close the connection.

Comment: Why i need such class to destroy is..one of my team member forget to close connection in his service so at the load test connection goes on increasing. after manually checking each service we come to know this so after closing connection now pool is working fine

Comment: @Amogh Right, I see that... But is the getConnection() method static? Or is it an instance method on a class which is instantiated on the level of the controller (i.e. via dependency injection)?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes its static method in which we check dataSource (DB pool obj) is null the perform connection pooling then return an connection from that pool. dataSource object is also static

Comment: How can i implement such class?

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with the connection in the first place. Use a `JdbcTemplate` to do the querying. If you really want to do stuff with the connection use a `ConnectionCallback`. Complete this with springs declarative transaction management and you have 1 problem less to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be messing with the connection in the first place. Use a [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to do the querying. If you really want to do stuff with the connection use a [`ConnectionCallback`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback-). Complete this with springs declarative transaction management and you have 1 problem less to solve.

If you really want to work with the `Connection` and refuse to use use the common approach of the `JdbcTemplate` you could fix this with Springs declarative transaction management. Wrap the datasource in a [`TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html). Then configure Spring to manage the transaction, this will ensure that during the transaction a single connection will be used and spring will close the connection at the end of the transaction.

I would however strongly suggest to move to the usage of the [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) as that will make your life a whole lot easier and allows you to solve the actual business problems

One other thing your service layer shouldn't be involved in JDBC coding that should be in a data access layer which is used by the service layer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, as u suggested first i ll go with `JDBCTemplate`.

Answer (score -2):

The following should work:

```
try{
  Connecition.close();
}
finally{
  System.err.println();
  Connection.close();
}
```